# How to use WebSql database with sencha touch Application

Tags: database, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, web-sql

I am working with sencha touch application to handle small database I have used local storage.

But, now I want to handle larger amount of database with SQL queries.

Can anyone suggest how to use a database system like Websql or any other database system with sencha touch?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create a web service (handling all the SQL) using your server language of choice (even Javascript is available using Node.JS for example). Call your web service from Sencha Touch using regular HTTP/AJAX.

Comment: can you suggest me some of good tutorials ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Ext.data.proxy.Sql

Refer these links

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Sql

http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/2013/04/19/sencha-touch-clarifying-websql-sqlite-and-how-they-relate-to-sencha-touch/