# list view is not populated in sencha touch 2 of localstorage web sql data

Tags: listview, sencha-touch-2, local-storage, store

I have a web sql database of browser. I just want to show the data of that table in my view class in sencha touch 2. But data is not being shown the view is empty here.I don't know why.Here is the code kindly help me out of someone knows the answer:

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.view.UsersView',{
extend:'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype:'userlist',

requires:[
            'Ext.dataview.List',
            'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage',
            'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
        ],
config:{
    title:  'User List',
    iconCls:    'star',

    items:[
            {
                xtype:      'list',
                itemTpl:    '{name}',
                title:  'Students',

                store:{
                    autoLoad:   true,
                    fields: ["name","email"],

                    proxy:{
                            type: 'localstorage',
                            id: 'Student'
                        }
                    }
            }

    ]
    }

});
```

here id is the name of the database in websql. I don't know what to write here exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For websql, you'll need to use the sql proxy, not localstorage.

You'll find more info on how to use it in the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Sql) and in [this blog post](http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/2013/04/19/sencha-touch-clarifying-websql-sqlite-and-how-they-relate-to-sencha-touch/), thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802073/how-to-use-websql-database-with-sencha-touch-application) post.

Comment: thanks for replying! so u mean Web SQL is separate than local storage? In my case i hav database in Web SQL category...

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 Ext.define('FirstApp.view.UsersView',{
extend:'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype:'userlist',

requires:[
            'Ext.dataview.List',
            'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage',
            'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
        ],
config:{
    title:  'User List',
    iconCls:    'star',

    items:[
            {
                xtype:      'list',
                itemTpl:    '{name}',
                title:  'Students',

                store:new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                    autoLoad:   true,
                    fields: ["name","email"],

                    proxy:{
                            type: 'localstorage',
                            id: 'Student'
                        }
                    })
            }

    ]
    }

});
```